# Mesh Generation with MeshPy

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to solve a FE problem in Python, but I'm stuck at the mesh generation stage. I've installed MeshPy v2014.1 using pip (so all dependencies should be sorted out), but the following example given on [the MeshPy website](http://documen.tician.de/meshpy/) doesn't seem to work.

```
from meshpy.tet import MeshInfo, build

mesh_info = MeshInfo()
mesh_info.set_points([
    (0,0,0), (2,0,0), (2,2,0), (0,2,0),
    (0,0,12), (2,0,12), (2,2,12), (0,2,12),
    ])
mesh_info.set_facets([
    [0,1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7],
    [0,4,5,1],
    [1,5,6,2],
    [2,6,7,3],
    [3,7,4,0],
    ])
mesh = build(mesh_info)
print "Mesh Points:"
for i, p in enumerate(mesh.points):
    print i, p
print "Point numbers in tetrahedra:"
for i, t in enumerate(mesh.elements):
    print i, t
mesh.write_vtk("test.vtk")
```

I've copy/pasted the code exactly. The example runs, but doesn't generate the result listed on the site. Instead, I get

```
Mesh Points:
0 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1 [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2 [2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
3 [0.0, 2.0, 0.0]
4 [0.0, 0.0, 12.0]
5 [2.0, 0.0, 12.0]
6 [2.0, 2.0, 12.0]
7 [0.0, 2.0, 12.0]
8 [2.0, 2.0, 6.0]
9 [0.0, 0.0, 6.0]
10 [0.0, 2.0, 6.0]
11 [2.0, 0.0, 6.0]
Point numbers in tetrahedra:
0 [2, 10, 0, 8]
1 [2, 0, 1, 8]
2 [4, 11, 9, 8]
3 [0, 10, 9, 8]
4 [6, 10, 4, 7]
5 [4, 11, 8, 5]
6 [0, 11, 1, 8]
7 [2, 10, 3, 0]
8 [6, 10, 8, 4]
9 [5, 4, 6, 8]
10 [0, 11, 8, 9]
11 [4, 10, 8, 9]
VtkData.__init__.warning:
      No data defined
```

The output file is written (test.vtk) but only contains the points (no mesh). I'm assuming that the `built(mesh_info)` command isn't working, but I can't find a way to trace the problem. The MeshPy documentation lists several flags that can be passed to `build()` but doesn't mention what they do. I tried `build(mesh_info,verbose=True)` but got no extra output. I then tried `build(mesh_info,diagnose=True)`, which halted with the following error:

```
ValueError: Cell 'tetra' requires exactly 4 points but got 0: <meshpy._tetgen.IntArray object at 0x7f288bba54b0>
```

I can't seem to find any other instances of this same problem. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the program called Paraview to visualize the output file. I tested the meshpy yesterday and it´s running correctly.

Comment: There is no mesh in the output file. I'm sure there is some site-dependant problem on my machine. In any case, this is an old problem that I've long since given up on.

Answer (score 0):

to generate vtk output, the code "meshpy" needs pyvtk installed on system.
you can install it easily using pip as well as meshpy